# Exchange 2007 Mailbox Full

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a user who recently married.  I changed her user name in AD which also changed her exchange 07 mailbox. We are redirecting emails to her old user name to her new mailbox. Now she is getting "Mail Box Full" messages from the exchange server to her old user name, which are forwarded to her new mailbox.  However her mailbox is well below the set size limits.  Even without any limits set on her account she gets a message each time she logs in. Each time the "Mailbox Full" message arrives the mailbox size listed has changed but it is still not the same size as her actual mailbox on the exchange server.

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas? All I can think of doing at this point it to save her mailbox to a .pst and then delete and recreate.

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason to maintain two separate mailboxes? I'd suggest just merging and adding an alias to whatever her "current" mailbox is.

Comment: There are not two mailboxes, that's what is hard to figure out. Her old mailbox was renamed via the user acount rename in AD.  So there is only one mailbox and smtp entries for her old email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our name-change process is as follows:

1. User submits the name-change form to HR.
2. HR processes the form, entering it into our automation systems.
3. Automation systems spit out an extract containing the 'address book' information for all active counts, the fields include among others:

   - First name
   - Last name
4. The account management system takes the extracts and updates fields wherever they've changed. When it gets to this user, it changes the first/last name as needed.
5. When the user is ready for the email change they notify the helpdesk.
6. The helpdesk hits a button in our account management page that makes the new first.last@ mail address the Reply-To to address for that account. All old email addresses are retained on the account.

The key thing here is that when a name changes (with on the order of 4000 people, this happens frequently) we just change their display data. We do not generate a new account. If their userID was smithk (Karen Smith), we won't change it to barnesk (Karen Barnes) if they change their last name. If a user presses the issue, hard, we will generate a completely new set of accounts for them, but it takes a lot of pressure to get us to do that. Because of this, if their name changes they don't get a completely new mail account, it's the same account just with a different name on the To and From lines.

In your case what I would do is this:

- Export the old mailbox to PST
- Import the PST to their new mailbox
- Add the old email address as an additional SMTP address to the new mailbox
- Delete the old mailbox

You may have to temporarily increase their mail quota to accommodate the PST import, then let them do the cleaning before you drop it again.